# requirejs dependency loading timeout

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am trying to load jquery plugins by defining jquery as a dependecy.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/assets/',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        jqueryujs: 'jquery_ujs',
        jquerybackstretch: 'jquery.backstretch',
        jquerysticky: 'sticky',
        jquerydialog: 'jquery.ui.dialog',
        app: 'index'
    },
    shim: {
        'jqueryujs': {
            deps: ['jqueryujs']
        },
        'jquerybackstretch': {
            deps: ['jquerybackstretch']
        },
        'jquerysticky': {
            deps: ['jquerysticky']
        },
        'jquerydialog': {
            deps: ['jquerydialog']
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['app']
        }
    }
})

require(['jquery', 'jquerybackstretch', 'jqueryujs', 'jquerysticky', 'jquerydialog', 'app'], function($) {

})
```

Here is the error message

```
Load timeout for modules: jquerybackstretch,jqueryujs,jquerysticky,jquerydialog,app
```

Whether I have loaded all the plugins correctly? Any other good practices to load plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that you have set circular dependencies in your shims. For instance:

```
'jqueryujs': {
    deps: ['jqueryujs']
}
```

This tells RequireJS that the module depends on itself. Presumably, all of the modules you have that have `jquery` in their names depend on jQuery so I would expect this:

```
shim: {
    'jqueryujs': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquerybackstretch': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquerysticky': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquerydialog': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

I do not know what (most of) these modules are so I can't tell if they depend on one another. You should check whether they do and add whatever is needed to the `deps` settings.

I do not know what your `app` module is. If it is a module you've created yourself to be loaded with RequireJS, then it should call `define` with an appropriate list of dependencies and you should not need a shim for it.

Comment: ya thanks problem solved. Above method I have used is alright else any other good practice to handle requirejs

Comment: What I've put in my answer is everything I can say that is relevant to your question.